# Google Cloud Source Repository: remote: PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission remote

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permission-denied

remote: PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission remote: [type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.RequestInfo]

Not able to clone, push the code into google cloud source repository. I have given "Project Editor" iam permission. I have successfully login with "gcloud login" command. I also have set the right default project configuration and account configuration using "gcloud config set project" and "gcloud config set account" commands.  Please help me with this PERMISSION_DENIED error.

Comment: Have you created an empty repo first in Google CSR?

Comment: Yes. I have created empty repo. I can be able to create, delete the repo from local machine gcloud command but when I try to clone or pull push it gives me the error.

Answer (score 7):

I had the exact same issue and I resolved it by adding a new entry in the .gitcookies file.

You have to manually generated and stored your Git credentials by login on this page: https://source.developers.google.com/auth/start?scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform&state=

That will ask you to login with your account and allow Google Cloud Development wants to access your Google Account. Then, you'll have the script you have to run.

Hope this helps you as well.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was that my free trial had ended and I needed to enable the billing here:
[https://console.developers.google.com/billing/enable?project=[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]](https://console.developers.google.com/billing/enable?project=%5BYOUR_PROJECT_ID%5D)

Answer (score 0):

For me this happened when I used SSH and connection re-use by a `ControlMaster` directive.
It seems like google's git implementation can't handle this.

For me either of these two worked:

- close the ssh connection with `ssh -O exit ...` (add your connection)
- delete the socket from the file system (specified by `ControlPath`)